# Marking External Library Sealed Class as Obsolete

Tags: c#, dll, sealed, obsolete

This is a bit of a nasty one;
I have an "external" library (technically internal to the company but the original source code is no longer available, just the DLL) with a `sealed` class that is/should be marked as obsolete.

Is it possible to do? I suspect I might need to mess around with reflection to get the job done (I'm more than OK with this), I'm just not clear on the details.

Answer (score -1):

How will you change the dll without source code?  If your company has no copyright issues, you can check the dll source code with tools jetbrains dotpeek. Prepare your own project and copy source code. Do remember not to decompile proprietary source code of other companies. There are legal issues with that and can cost heavily.

Comment: As mentioned, it's internal to the company, so copyright isn't an issue. I'd prefer not to replicate the entire DLL, I was hoping there might be a way to create a class with some reflection magic that overrides the target class in the DLL.

Comment: Reflection in read and execute mode. It cannot update the class inside dll.